# How to vectorize a subsetting function in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

I've had some luck vectorizing certain functions, which is great for clean code, avoiding loops, and speed.

However, I have not been able to vectorize any function which subsets a dataframe based on the inputs to the function

#### Example

E.g. This function works well when it receives elements

```
test_funct <- function(sep_wid, sep_len) {
    iris %>% filter(Sepal.Width > sep_wid & Sepal.Length < sep_len) %>% .$Petal.Width %>% sum
}

test_funct(4, 6)

# [1] 0.7 # This works nicely
```

But when attempting to provide vectors as inputs to this function:

```
sep_wid_vector <- c(4, 3.5, 3)
sep_len_vector <- c(6, 6, 6.5)


test_funct(sep_wid_vector, sep_len_vector)

[1] 9.1
```

But the desired output is a vector of the same length as the input vectors, as though the function was run on the first elements of each vector, then the second, then the third. i.e.

```
# 0.7    4.2     28.5
```

For convenience, here output as if these were all run separately

```
test_funct(4, 6) # 0.7
test_funct(3.5, 6) # 4.2
test_funct(3, 6.5) # 28.5
```

How can I vectorize a function that subsets data based on its inputs so that it can receive vector inputs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `filter` takes vector inputs, so it will recycle the vectors in the `Sepal.width` and `Sepal.length` comparisons.

One way to do this would be to use `map2` from the `purrr` package:

```
map2_dbl(sep_wid_vector, sep_len_vector, test_funct)
```

Of course you could then wrap this in a function. You might also want to consider passing in the data frame as a function parameter.

Comment: @thothal great find with `purrr::map2_dbl`. For completeness, `mapply(test_funct, sep_wid_vector, sep_len_vector)` also works

Answer (score 5):

You can use  `Vectorize`:

```
tv <- Vectorize(test_funct)

tv(sep_wid_vector, sep_len_vector)
# [1]  0.7  4.2 28.5
```

This is basically a wrapper around `mapply`. Be aware that under the hood you are running an `*apply` function, which is alos sort of a loop

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way using `sapply`

```
# function using sapply
test_funct <- function(sep_wid, sep_len) {
  sapply(seq_along(sep_wid), function(x) {
    sum(iris$Petal.Width[iris$Sepal.Width > sep_wid[x] & iris$Sepal.Length < sep_len[x]])
  })
}

# testing with single value
test_funct(4,6)
[1] 0.7

# testing with vectors
test_funct(sep_wid_vector, sep_len_vector)
[1]  0.7  4.2 28.5
```